# Discrete VS finite groups

Tags: finite-groups, topological-groups

I am having some troubles to understand what the difference is between discrete and finite groups. I know they are defined differently, I can't quite understand the difference. I am guessing every finite group but the viceversa is not true. Could someone make this clear and give an example?

Thanks,
Eduardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are completely different objects.

A finite group is just that, a group with finitely many elements.

A discrete group is a topological group, where the topology is discrete.

An example of a finite, but not discrete group is ANY finite group with no topology on it, or not the discrete one.

An example of discrete, but not finite group is ANY infinite group with the discrete topology.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Just one question, why can't you define a discrete topology for every finite group, just saying that each element is an open set?

Comment: @EduardoGarcía You can define the discrete topology on ANY group, or any set even.

Comment: Note that a lot of people working with topological groups will always assume the topology is Hausdorff (or one of the weaker things which implies Hausdorff for topological groups anyway), and then any finite topological group is indeed discrete.